# Can I enable gzip/deflate in IIS6 without restart?

Tags: iis-6, compression

I have gone through the steps of enabling static compression for my IIS 6.0 site:

1. enable it in IIS Manager
2. enable edit-while-running
3. add the extensions i need to compress directly to the metabase: js, css
4. wait for the metabase.xml to update to the latest major history version

It is still not compressing JS and CSS. Is there anyway to enable this without iisreset?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following step by step at http://www.jasonlinham.co.uk/2009/06/turn-on-iis-6-compression-for-css-and.html (including the content here just in case)

**Turn on IIS 6 Compression for CSS and Javascript**

**Enable HTTP Compression**

1. Open IIS Manager Right-click "Web
2. Site" and select "Services" tab.
3. Check "Compress Static Files"
4. Click "Okay"

**Specify that "js" and "css" file should be compressed by changing the metabase. By default, IIS 6.0 is set up to compress htm, html, and txt files.**

1. Open a command prompt
2. cd to C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts (assuming the default location)
3. run this command (you can change the list of extensions, but only specify static, compressible files here): `cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set w3svc/Filters/Compression/GZIP/HcFileExtensions "htm" "html" "txt" "js" "css"`

**Restart the World Wide Web Publishing Service**

Answer (score 0):

Check [this out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vivekkum/http-compression-in-iis-6-and-iis-7-using-service-account)

You can check the following in the Metabase.xml file

[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/vivekkum/WindowsLiveWriter/HTTPCOMPRESSIONinIIS6andIIS7_1245B/image_17.png))</sub>

Hope this helps,

Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Follow *all* the steps in this tutorial:

http://engineering.leads360.com/post/9301650692/http-compression-gzip-on-iis-6